# Check that JSONB array *does not* contain string?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, where-clause, jsonb

I would like to select rows where a JSONB column ***does not*** contain a value. I see how to check for existence (`WHERE vegetables::jsonb ? 'carrots'`), but not the opposite. Can anyone help?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just negate that condition:

```
WHERE NOT (vegetables::jsonb ? 'carrots')
```